# passing and returning a variable to a function in r

Tags: r, function, substitution

I created a function and want to replace x by another variable called s and set y=3, Z=c(1,2), z=Z[2]. y,z are always fixed, x is random.

```
myfun <- function(x, y, z){ x + y + x*z}
```

How to do it so that the function with return s+3+2s or 3+3s? And then (3+3s) will become a (new) function depending on s?

```
myfun <- function(x, y, z){ substitute(x + y + x*z)}
```

returns s+3+s*Z[2]

```
myfun <- function(x, y, z){ substitute(x) + y + substitute(x)*z}
```

gives me an error of non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the `substitute` function

```
myfun <- function(x, y){ substitute(x + y) }
myfun(s, 3)
# s + 3
```